# How to insert data if not in between in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

If I have a table of events like this:

```
    event_name     begin_date(pk) end_date(pk)
    ------------------------------------------
    holiday        2014-11-01     2014-11-05
    holiday        2014-11-10     2014-11-12
    big sale       2014-11-18     2014-11-25
    monthly sale   2014-11-28     2014-11-30
```

How can I prevent inserting data if `begin_date` or `end_date` of the inserted data is in the period of any events?

Example:
This data won't be inserted:

```
    holiday        2014-11-03     2014-11-08
```

this data will be inserted:

```
    holiday        2014-11-06     2014-11-09
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Learn SQL. Read up on triggers. Write one that stops the insert.

Comment: Tom is right, you can use Triggers for this. Also, you can use Check Constraint on table. Check this URL for check constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Possibly worth a read [Storing intervals of time with no overlaps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to avoid triggers and perform a check with if exists before inserting

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM MyTable WHERE @InsertedEndDate > begin_date AND @InsertedBeginDate < end_date)
BEGIN
    --do actual insert/work
END
```

Its a simple check to find the first overlap. The Select TOP 1 1 is a trick to avoid actually fetching the data, it will return as soon as it matches a row that overlaps the date range you're actually trying to save

Comment: This is not a thread safe method. Two separate threads could insert the rows at the same time. Also, [`TOP 1` is not necessary in `EXISTS`](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/04/05/to-top-or-not-to-top-an-exists/)

Comment: @GarethD this is truly safe only if you lock that is true. Two rows could not lock at the same time to update or insert tough, so one would inevitably fail. Good point about the TOP in exists, I never tought about it

Comment: Sadly [that is not true](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx), AFIK using [MERGE WITH (HOLDLOCK)](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx) is the best (and possibly only) way to ensure a race condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers should be your last resort. If your application uses a stored procedure, it's better if you put the validation there. Or you could use a [`check constraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). This is the condition you need to use, from what I understand of your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE @begin_date BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date
OR @end_date BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date
OR @begin_date < begin_date AND @end_date > end_date
```

If that query returns any rows, those `@begin_date` and `@end_date` values should't be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I always think that if something can be constrained in the database, it should be. You never know which developer is going to disable a trigger, or bypass application code and run the insert directly, so while triggers and business logic is good, it is not fool proof.

The first thing I would do is constrain begin_date to be before end_date:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Event_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    begin_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE dbo.T ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_T_ValidDates CHECK (Begin_date <= end_date);
```

Then (if you don't already have one) you can create a calendar table ([which are incredibly useful anyway](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql)):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar 
(
    Date DATE NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_Calendar_Date ON dbo.Calendar (Date);
GO
INSERT dbo.Calendar (Date)
SELECT  TOP (7305) DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, '20000101')
FROM    sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects;
GO
```

Finally you can create an indexed view, to ensure that no dates are duplicated in your table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.TCheck
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  c.Date
    FROM    dbo.T
            INNER JOIN dbo.Calendar AS c
                ON c.Date >= t.begin_date 
                AND c.Date <= t.end_date;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_TCheck_ID ON dbo.TCheck (Date);
```

In the tests I ran (comparing to a trigger) the indexed view performed about 50% better than the trigger, but neither performed well. Unfortunately, sometimes data integrity has a cost.