# SQL constraint check with date from table linked with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, created with the following SQL queries:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
     user_email varchar(255) not null primary key,
     --other unimportant columns
     subscription_start date not null,
     subscription_end date,
     CONSTRAINT chk_end_start CHECK (subscription_start != subscription_end)
)

CREATE TABLE action
(
     --unimportant columns
     user_email varchar(255) not null,
     action_date date not null,
     CONSTRAINT FK_user FOREIGN KEY (user_email) REFERENCES user(user_email)
)
```

What I would like to do is make sure with some sort of check constraint that the `action_date` is between the `subscription_start` and `subscription_end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do using check constraints, since check constraints can only refer to columns inside the same table. Furthermore, foreign key constraints only support equi-joins.

If you must perform this check at the database level instead of your application level, you could do it using a trigger on INSERT/UPDATE on the action-table. Each time a record is inserted or updated, you check whether the action_date lies within the corresponding subscription_start/end dates on the user-table. If that is not the case, you use the RAISERROR function, to flag that the row can not be inserted/updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ActionDateTrigger ON tblaction
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tbluser u JOIN inserted i ON i.user_email = u.user_email
      AND i.action_date BETWEEN u.subscription_start AND u.subscription_end
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Action_date outside valid range', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

Comment: when trying that bit of SQL, I get the following error: `The multi-part identifier "inserted.user_email" could not be bound` and a similar one on the inserted.action_date. What is the cause for this?

Comment: Sorry - the `inserted` virtual table must be used in a join, rather than directly in the where-criteria. I've edited my answer - it should work now.

Answer (score 3):

I always try to avoid triggers where possible, so thought I would throw an alternative into the mix. You can use an indexed view to validate data here. First you will need to create a new table, that simply contains two rows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Two (Number INT NOT NULL);
INSERT dbo.Two VALUES (1), (2);
```

Now you can create your indexed view, I have used `ActionID` as the implied primary key of your `Action` table, but you may need to change this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ActionCheck
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  a.ActionID
    FROM    dbo.[User] AS u
            INNER JOIN dbo.[Action] AS a
                ON a.user_email = u.user_email
            CROSS JOIN dbo.Two AS t
    WHERE   a.Action_date < u.subscription_start
    OR      a.Action_date > u.subscription_end
    OR      t.Number = 1;
GO;
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_ActionCheck_ActionID ON dbo.ActionCheck (ActionID);
```

So, your view will always return one row per action (`t.Number = 1` clause), however, the row in `dbo.Two` where number = 2 will be returned if the action date falls outside of the subscription dates, this will cause duplication of `ActionID` which will violate the unique constraint on the index, so will stop the insert. e.g.:

```
INSERT [user] (user_email, subscription_start, subscription_end) 
VALUES ('test@test.com', '20140101', '20150101');

INSERT [Action] (user_email, action_date) VALUES ('test@test.com', '20140102');
-- WORKS FINE UP TO THIS POINT

-- THIS NEXT INSERT THROWS AN ERROR
INSERT [Action] (user_email, action_date) VALUES ('test@test.com', '20120102');
```

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ActionCheck' with unique index 'UQ_ActionCheck_ActionID'. The duplicate key value is (6).
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I like the creativity of using indexed views to enforce a constraint among multiple interrelated tables, but I can't help but think that there must still be some sort of overhead of doing it this way. I wonder how the performance compares to using triggers?

Comment: Re `ActionID`: It only requires `Action` to have a primary key, it does not matter what this is, and I think I covered this in the answer - *"I have used ActionID as the implied primary key of your Action table, but you may need to change this"*

Comment: Re Performance: I would not expect the indexed view to perform worse than the trigger, in the same way a foreign key constraint is more efficient than the same check done in a trigger. I ran some tests for a similar scenario for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26785510/1048425), and found that maintaining the indexed view was cheaper than using a trigger, however, I don't think it is a one size fit's all solution, and there will be situations (this could be one) where a trigger will perform better. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is like so:
- in table action create a check constraint that calls a function like so: check(dbo.FcToCheckValidity(user_email, action_date) = 1)
- the dbo.FcToCheckValidity function would be something like:
-- FcToCheckValidity(user_email , action_date) returning BIT
-- query user table and: if input action_date between subscription_start and subscription_end for the correct user THEN return 1 else 0.

Comment: [Scalar UDFs wrapped in CHECK constraints are very slow and may fail for multirow updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

actually, an indexed view requires "reindexing" when data has changed in the table. Performance will suffer if it's a rather complex view or has lotos of rows. I also believe that a trigger in this case would perform better...